# Macro to change spelling of 1 particular word after it is typed

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I would like to do a prank on a friend who is a school teacher & always corrects everyone's spelling in email / letters / cards that we send to her.

Basically this person spells her name a certain way but I would like it automatically changed to an incorrect spelling after she types it just to annoy her.

So if she types something like "Caitlyn" I would like the macro to automatically change the word to be spelt "Katelyn".

Has anyone done anything like this before or know if a Microsoft Word macro could do this?

EDIT: I am not asking anyone to write code for me, I would like to know if a Word Macro can do this otherwise I won't waste my time playing with Macro's & will just write a basic app to do it.

Comment: At first we're not a free-code writing service, you need to show effort and ask specific questions. Also, any macro works in the document only when it's included, so: you need to make the macro, get your friend enables macros in them and insert her name in it. It will not work in other documents / tools.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I have not asked anyone to write any code for me so I'm not sure why you would insinuate that. All I am asking is if a Word Macro can do this otherwise I will just look at writing a simple app in C# to do it.

Comment: So for your question the answer is "yes, a word macro could do it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a Macro. It can be added to autocorrect:

1. Open Word Options

[image]

2. Go to the autocorrect tab.

[image]

3. Add the original word, for example **"Caitlyn"** and the auto corrected form of the word, for example **"Katelyn"**.

Comment: How it can be done on somebody else's computer?

Comment: That's probably even a better idea as it does not need to be permanent - it just has to annoy her for a few days or weeks! Thanks for the idea :)

Comment: The dictionary settings are per-user, which means in this case that you must gain access to the computer while the intended victim is logged on. You'd have to do the same if you wanted to set up a macro-based solution too, so this isn't an issue unique to this solution.